# Rewriting functions from r to python

Tags: python, r, function

I have function written in R.

```
V <- function(c, E, HS, EC_50) E + (1 - E) / (1 + exp(HS * (c - EC_50))
```

I would like to get the same function in Python but I don't know how. I haven't used Python very much before. Therefore, I am asking for forum  help.

Comment: Check [ask] and [tour]. SO is not code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lambda` expression

```
import numpy as np
v = lambda c, E, HS, EC_50: E + (1 - E) / (1 + np.exp(HS * (c - EC_50)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

def v(c, E, HS, EC_50):
    return E + (1 - E) / (1 + np.exp(HS * (c - EC_50)))
```